How to get the LocalePath() and return a path with the locales in Nuxt3 Server
How can I get the localePath() from Nuxt 3 server?
// server/api/[...].ts

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    // The secret is used to encrypt the JWT token
    secret: useRuntimeConfig().auth.secret,

    // Redirects to this page if the user is not authenticated
    pages: {
        // * How to get the locales Path and return?
        signIn: '/zh-TW/auth/',  // '/en-US/auth/'
    },
....

As i18n can only be used in Nuxt3 but not the Nitro. What can I do to redirect a path with the locale path from server to frontend?

Not the best way, but you can use cookies to get to know locale. For this, you can use parseCookies() as shown in docs.
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  ...
  const cookies = parseCookies(event)
  ...
})

I will update this response if I find any better way.

Yes, wrapping with eventHandler, can able to get the locales data from event,  and return the NuxtAuthHandler, is one of the method, but this will cause warning on calling more than one NuxtAuthHandler.

Maybe we can just check if the user is logged in on accessing some page.
Just add a middleware for nuxt3 (not server)
// middleware/permissionChecker.ts (not server middleware)
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const {data} = useAuth();
    console.log(data.value)
    if (!data.value?.user) {
        return navigateTo(useLocalePath()('/auth/'));  // Redirect to login page
    }
    // Continue to the next page if user logged in.
});


And use it on the page which need to check if user logged
definePageMeta({
    middleware: 'permission-checker'
})

Then you may redirect to the login page with correct locale path.
